# How can I generate a Payment Nonce using braintree-web js file for ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I getting a compiling error after running npm Braintree and including the .js file in typescript and ionic2

Comment: Include the error message and add more description.

Comment: So I installed braintree using npm install braintree and it sits under node_modules directory now. There is no typescript file associated to it as it is a pure javascript library.

Comment: So not sure how do I import it like I import moment.js using statement:

import moment = require('moment');

I found braintree.d.ts file https://gist.github.com/stwiname/a455abc0947b16a60301244b8cf0c7d5. Do I have to include it somewhere? Is this file even relevant or I can use the braintree JS library directly. 

Is it even possible to use braintree with ionic2 at the moment?


Sorry for so many questions, I am new to typescript and still trying to learn it.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the braintree typescript type definition https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/braintree-web/braintree-web.d.ts .

You can install it though nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/braintree-web.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

or NPM through typings https://github.com/typings/typings

Alternatively, To resolve typescript compile errors for external libraries without a type definition file, you can declare the unrecognized variables with typescript type `any`, for example `declare var Braintree: any;` or create your own typescript type declaration, more info http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html

There is also a tool that helps you convert JsDoc to d.ts https://github.com/englercj/tsd-jsdoc

Comment: let me try.. I will keep you posted. Thanks